# how to change svg image top to bottom?

Tags: jquery, svg, snap.svg, svg-edit

I have two svg image a page Please see the below link,

I want top need to come upper. want are the attribute need to change using jquery , Please any one help, i am not well in svg image

```
<g id="svg_1" class="svg_19 deg_0 cat_bot stage 10_10 ">
<path id="path3806" class="carpet" d="M221.00011003017426,387.9259910583496 L221.00011003017426,340 L260.9421691894531,340 L300.8841323852539,340 L300.8778076171875,346.49350023269653 C300.8673629760742,355.5559997558594 298.18566131591797,371.7194995880127 295.3823928833008,379.60350036621094 C284.0830307006836,411.3825225830078 259.24842834472656,431.6875 227.43985986709595,435.1505126953125 L220.99997997283936,435.8517379760742 L220.99997997283936,387.92572021484375 L221.00010001659393,387.9259796142578 L221.00011003017426,387.9259796142578 L221.00011003017426,387.9259910583496 z" fill="#fefefe">
 <path id="path3744" class="fascia" d="M221.28154003620148,387.70930099487305 L221.56252002716064,340.5453100204468 L260.84997940063477,340.2727999985218 L300.13739013671875,339.99999000000025 L299.5337219238281,353.2599802017212 C298.5851364135742,374.09397888183594 292.4382629394531,390.77997970581055 279.9669494628906,406.3799819946289 C267.37292861938477,422.1319885253906 247.63364028930664,432.90897369384766 228.837739944458,434.29496002197266 L221,434.87296295166016 L221.28102004528046,387.70896911621094 L221.28154003620148,387.7092781066...1.3706200122833 235.22611045837402,341.74414002895355 L222.1022698879242,342.42328000068665 L222.1022698879242,378.6272888183594 L222.1022698879242,414.83130645751953 L227.32703018188477,414.83130645751953 C230.20069026947021,414.83130645751953 236.29081916809082,413.9109573364258 240.86025047302246,412.7861022949219 L240.86083030700684,412.7863082885742 L240.86086082458496,412.7863082885742 L240.86086082458496,412.7862777709961 L240.86086082458496,412.7863006591797 L240.86087036132812,412.7863006591797 z" fill="#8e8e8e">
```

[image: View to image]

Comment: Share your svg html code so that we can help you.

Comment: I have give svg image code

Answer (score 0):

Assuming each square in your picture is 10px:

```
$('#svg_1').attr('transform', 'translate (10, -30)');
```